# PHP get variable value from array

Tags: php, arrays

If i print an array `$cat` i get

```
Array ( [1] => stdClass Object ( [cat_id] => 1 ..
Array ( [2] => stdClass Object ( [cat_id] => 2 ..
```

but if I try to get the `cat_id`

```
var_dump($cat->cat_id);
```

How can i do that?

Comment: You need an offset for your `$cat` array: `var_dump($cat[0]->cat_id);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($cat AS $singleCat){
   echo $singleCat->cat_id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$cat` is an Array.

So,

```
var_dump($cat[1]->cat_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

try `var_dump($cat[0]->cat_id);`

Answer (score 1):

`$cat` is an array. You need to access the index which contains an object before you can access that object's properties:

```
var_dump($cat[1]->cat_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

As `$cat` is an array, you need to use index

```
var_dump($cat[1]->cat_id);//This will work
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all of the `cat_id`s...

```
foreach ($cat as $row) {
  echo $row->cat_id;
}
```